# Use different username by default for a specific host

Tags: ssh, users

I have a different (assigned, non-changable) username on one of the servers I log to regularly, and I would like to avoid writing it down every time. Can I make these lines

```
[tohecz@localhost ~]$ ssh myserver.cz
[tohecz@localhost ~]$ ssh anotherserver.cz
```

behave as the following?

```
[tohecz@localhost ~]$ ssh tohecz@myserver.cz
[tohecz@localhost ~]$ ssh anotheruser@anotherserver.cz
```

Comment: Can I ask why the question got downvoted? Have I done anything wrong? If so, please exaplain it to me so that I can improve the post.

Comment: I did not DV this but typically Q's that are very basic such as this or show little effort in searching prior to asking are viewed negatively. Also searching this site would've yielded many A's that show the below A: http://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=ssh+user+host

Comment: @slm I've tried searching `ssh username` which did not give any reasonable response :-/

Comment: Understand, but that is likely the reasons for the DV.

Comment: @tohecz Looking at `man ssh_config` and searching for `User` gives the result in about 30 sec. So, as slm says, it is very basic. I'm not suggesting asking such a question is a bad thing - one does have to know where to look, and that may not be obvious. I ask basic questions sometimes too, but some people may not like it. I'm also not justifying the downvote. I don't believe in them, except for spam.

Comment: @FaheemMitha That sounds like I should know where to look. I consider any further discussion in this manner pointless.

Comment: @tohecz At the risk of redundancy, no disrespect or offense to you is intended. This was by way of response to you asking about the downvote.

Comment: @yo' knowing about man pages (e,g. running `man ssh` if you want to know something about ssh) is very basic unix/linux knowledge.  As is knowing that man pages follow a very standardised format with common section headings - including the SEE ALSO heading, under which the man page will refer you to related man pages.  In the case of `man ssh`, one of the other man pages it refers the reader to is `ssh_config`.  Not exactly obscure or difficult to find.  I wouldn't have down-voted your question but i can understand why some would.

Comment: sorry, i didn't even look at or notice the post's date. it just appeared in the list of active questions.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Add the following in your `~/.ssh/config` file:

```
Host myserver.cz
  User tohecz

Host anotherserver.cz
  User anotheruser
```

You can specify a lot of default parameters for your hosts using this file. Just have a look at [man ssh_config](http://linux.die.net/man/5/ssh_config) for other possibilities.

Comment: Regarding other default parameters, I like shortening the host, along the lines of `Host web / Hostname www.mysite.com / User foo`

Comment: why only link to a web site for documentation that would be installed on almost every system with the openssh client installed?  links die.  local man pages are forever.  at least mention that the info is available by running `man ssh_config`.

Answer (score 2):

## How to have **default** *and* **host-specific** users

To be clear, if you want BOTH a **default** user AND **host-specific** users, you need to use `Host *`, and put it at the bottom of the config file:

`~/.ssh/config`:

```
#
# Aliases
#

Host dev
    Hostname dev.example.com

Host mac
    Hostname mac.local


#
# Host-specific users
#

Host dev dev.example.com
    User root

Host mac mac.local
    User me


#
# Default user
#

Host *
    User app
```

## References

- https://therootcompany.com/blog/ssh-defaults-config-and-priorities/